# What is the status of #resource ('main.css') in dart

Tags: dart

I dont see it being used much anymore, the DartEditor seems to claim its deprecated, is it deprecated? Does anyone have some publicly tracked history on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [dartbug 4429](http://dartbug.com/4429) it is being depreciated and removed from the spec.

Further more, according to this [source commit](https://code.google.com/p/dart/source/detail?r=4493), the `#resource` directive was ignored by the VM(s) and only used by the DartEditor itself.

Update: Official [notice](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/topic/misc/M6w_dTvl79o/discussion) on Dart-misc discussion group confirms #resource is being slated for removal.